# Rpi Camera in ubuntu server 20.04 raspistill working, but python picamera and c++ raspicam not

Tags: raspicam, ubuntu, picamera, 64-bit

I have been able to get the rpi camera v2 working on ubuntu server 20.04 (64bit) by using raspistill. However I am having trouble getting it to work with the python package picamera and the c++ package RaspiCam. For both i am getting the following error:

`mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.camera_info'`

I have found https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/688 which indicates that it should not work.

However I have also found https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/334#issuecomment-413415610 which has found a way to make it work.
I have tried adding the relevant code to the cmakelist.txt, but that did not help

So now I am not whether it is possible or not.

Have any of you been able to get this to work? If so what steps am i missing?